# Popular list and counting views in octobercms

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am trying to create a trending or popular list of categories in my application but not sure how it works or if what i have works as it should. In my category table, i added a `view_count` column. In the php block i have

```
$viewed = Cat::where('parent_id','>',0)->first();
$viewed->increment('view_count',1);
$viewed->save();
```

```
$this['trending'] = Cat::orderBy('view_count', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```

How do i correctly do this and add session to it so it does not count with each reload by a user?

Edit: I currently have this looking at how it is done in laravel. Dont know if it works differently with october

```
public function show(Cat $cat)
    {

$id = $cat->id;
$cat = Cat::find($id)->where('parent_id', '>', 0)->increment('view_count');


$this['trending'] = Cat::orderBy('view_count')->take(10)->get(); 

}
```

Comment: have you checked my answer ?

Comment: Yes i am trying it now. Trying to figure out how to query for the category_id. I didnt take that into consideration

Comment: I updated my question with what i have now. Don't know if it works any differently with october

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you would have **category_id** on trending category page so your code for incrementing view count must have been

```
Cat::find($category_id)->increment('view_count');
```

and that's it.

let me know if you need more help